# While I am trying to run Azure Devops CI/CD pipeline, I am encountering error: Browserslist: caniuse-lite is outdated

Tags: node.js, angular, azure-devops, continuous-integration, node-modules

While I am trying to run Azure Devops CI/CD pipeline, I am encountering

> error: Browserslist: caniuse-lite is outdated.Please run:
> ERROR: npx browserslist@latest --update-db

Although I have already ran the command `npx browserslist@latest --update-db` in angular cli & pushed the changes, still the error persists in Azure devops pipeline.